# Apply system wide screen rotation

Tags: settings, system

I've recently replaced a screen on my phone and it displays images slightly rotated. It's just a couple of pixels but it's really annoying.
I was wondering if there was some setting or API method to rotate whole system image, not just a single view image?

Comment: Hi, the title stated "Apple". Is the issue about iPhone or Android devices? Note that for Apple-related products, it's off-topic here but on-topic on our sister site, [apple.se]. Otherwise, consider mentioning the device model and Android version.

Comment: You can't rotate the content for just a few pixels. If the screen is mounted with a small rotation then you have to fix that by rotating the display (repairing).

Comment: @Robert No, it's not the screen that is rotated, it's an image. Straight lines drawn by the applications are not parallel to the pixel lines.